# Mac os help browser fails requiring internet connection

Tags: macos, system, bundle

I am developing an application for Mac OS X (I am new to that kind of things) and I want to include online help. The help is generated using doxygen and the help index generated using Help Indexer. I changed the Info.plist to point to the documentation, but when I try to access it, I get the following error:

> Internet connection required.
>
> The help topic you’re opening requires an Internet connection.
> Choose Apple > System Preferences, and
> then click Network to check your
> network settings and, if necessary,
> connect to the Internet.

Obviously, the computer I develop on has internet access that works, but more importantly, I would like to know why I need Internet while the help is on the drive (there are some links to internet in the help though). And also, why doesn't the browser see the existing internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently. I had some temporary links which went to pages I hadn't yet created. The problem was that Apple Help Viewer couldn't find a local copy of the linked pages. The Error message went away after I created the pages. IIRC my actual problem was an img tag for an image I had not yet created.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I am generating the page with Doxygen, I am pretty sure there are no missing pages ... Plus I really didn't find any!

Comment: Ok, that was the problem ! To find which page is problematic, I used the Activity window of Safari (found on another web site).\
Thanks